# Request.BinaryRead with Java HttpURLConnection.getHeaderFieldKey

Tags: java, vbscript, asp-classic

I have an ASP application that uploads a PDF file through `Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes)`. The requests that I make, are made through a java application. The problem is that I have method in Java that iterates through the Header Field Keys of the object HttpURLConnection. When the iteration is made I get in my ASP code an error "cannot call binaryread after using request.form".
Here is my java code:

```
 public String getCookieValue(HttpURLConnection con, String cookieKey) {
    String cookieValue = null;
    String headerName = null;
    for (int i = 1; (headerName = con.getHeaderFieldKey(i)) != null; i++) {
        if (headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {
            String cookie = con.getHeaderField(i);
            cookie = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf(";"));
            String cookieName = cookie.substring(0, cookie.indexOf("="));
            if (cookieName.equals(cookieKey)) {
                cookieValue = cookie.substring(cookie.indexOf("=") + 1, cookie.length());
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

The exact line of java code that breaks my ASP application is `con.getHeaderFieldKey(i)`. When I upload the file without this Java application, the file is uploaded properly.

What can I do to bypass this issue ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem here was that we are using a wrapper for the Session object. When we are trying to retrieve the information regarding the session Id we are using the Request.From method, and this intervenes with the Request.BinaryRead method which generates an error.